# Python: short syntax for accessing multiple properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I have a Python object with a lot of properties (say, twenty). I want to put about half of them in a tuple. I'll write:

```python
# Sample property names
myTuple = (myObj['one'], myObj['five'], myObj['six'],
    myObj['seven'], myObj['nine'], myObj['ten'],
    myObj['eleven'], myObj['fifteen'], myObj['twenty'])
```

Problem is, I have to repeat the name of the source object numerous times. Is there a more terse syntax? I would love something similar to this:

```python
# Sample property names
myTuple = myObj[('one', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'nine',
    'ten', 'eleven', 'fifteen', 'twenty')]
```

Comment: Just to be clear is your input an object i.e `myObj.one` or a dict i.e. `myObj['one']`?

Comment: Note that parentheses are not needed in `myObj[('one', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'fifteen', 'twenty')]`

Comment: For a mapping, it would be `itemgetter`, not `attrgetter`.

Comment: @chepner yep. It was because the OP used the word `object` that I suggested `attrgetter. I guess there is some terminology confusion.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module to extract elements from an object or a dictionary. For an object use [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter), for a `dict` use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). It returns a function, so you still have to invoke the function it returns passing the object from which you need to extract the values.

```
from operator import attrgetter, itemgetter

class X:
    def __init__(self, one, two, three):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
        self.three = three

# for object
x = X(1,2,3)
print(attrgetter('one', 'two')(x))

# for dict
y = {'one': 1, 'two':2, 'three': 3}
print(itemgetter('one', 'two')(y))
```

The good thing about it returning a function is that you can store the function and invoke it multiple times on as many objects as you want.

If you wished to keep the getter function then simply assign it to a variable

e.g.

```
fn = itemgetter('one', 'two')
fn(y)
# invoke on other dict(s) here
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look a bit into list comprehension. It's very handy for stuff like this. You could also write a method for your class, which takes in a list of properties and returns them in a tuple, which would even be a nicer solution in my opinion.

```
mytup = tuple([myObj[x] for x in ['one', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'nine',
'ten', 'eleven', 'fifteen', 'twenty']])
```

Comment: To avoid writing lots of quotes and commas, I would write `'one fix six ...'.split()`

Comment: I think that makes the code slightly less readable, and might cause problems if the key or whatever `__getitem__` might be using has spaces in it. But that's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `__getitem__` method of an object to implement this alternative behavior:

```
class dict2(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if isinstance(k, tuple):
            return tuple(self[x] for x in k)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
```

Example:

```
>>> d=dict2(a=1, b=2, c=4, d=8)
>>> d['a']
1
>>> d['a', 'd']
(1, 8)
>>> d['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
(1, 2, 4, 8)
```

Note that this will prevent you from using tuples as keys.

Comment: Also, if you ,for some reason, need them returned as nested tuples this is the way to go. `print(d['a', ('b', 'c')])` -> `(1, (2, 4))`